# Can i create a workflow without Sharepoint Designer 2007?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, workflow, custom

I dont have the ability to edit sites in SPD 2007 but I do have SPD. Could I somehow create a workflow template and upload it to the site? Or is there any 3rd part software that will work to create workflows on the site? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to access SharePoint from SharePoint designer to use the tool.

As for 3rd party there are quite a few. Two popular are Nintex Workflow, and K2.  Both have a significant cost associated with them and require server owners to deploy them.  They do however allow you to create workflows from within the browser without needing an additional tool.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have server access. Sounds like i will be stuck with the out of the box workflows.